# UIActivityViewController not sharing images

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, uiimage, uiactivityviewcontroller

The below code intends to share different text and different images (`UIImage` and `NSData`) depending on the different platform selected. The trouble is that none of the images are being passed from `activityImageShare()` to the `UIActivityViewController`.

**Question:**

> What’s could be wrong here exactly?
>
> How can I correct the code below to ensure that `activityImageShare()`
>   shares the images, and ensure they are picked up as an `activityType`
>   by `UIActivityViewController`?

**Code:**

1 - Four images, three `UIImage` and one `NSData`.

```
var myImage1: UIImage! 
var myImage2: UIImage!
var myImage3: NSData!
var myImage4: UIImage!
```

2 - Define images based on platform selected to pass to `UIActivityViewController`.

```
class activityImageShare: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    @objc func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
        return ""
    }
    @objc func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
        switch activityType {
        case UIActivityTypePostToFacebook:
            return myImage1
        case UIActivityTypePostToTwitter:
            return myImage2
        case UIActivityTypePostToWeibo:
            return myImage3
        default:
            return myImage4
        }
    }
}
```

3 - Define text based on platform selected to pass to `UIActivityViewController`.

```
class activityTextShare: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    @objc func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
        return ""
    }
    @objc func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
        switch activityType {
        case UIActivityTypePostToFacebook:
            return "This is my text 1."
        case UIActivityTypePostToTwitter:
            return "This is my text 2."
        case UIActivityTypePostToWeibo:
            return "This is my text 3."
        default:
            return "This is my text 4."
        }
    }
}
```

4 - Present `UIActivityViewController` based on text and images defined in `activityTextShare()` and `activityImageShare()`.

```
func myShareActivity() {
    let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityTextShare(), activityImageShare()], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try return placeholder image in `activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController)` instead of ""